# Reference request for the independence of $ \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $.

Tags: reference-request, logic, set-theory, first-order-logic, incompleteness

Gödel’s Second Incompleteness Theorem says that if $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ is consistent, then $ \mathsf{ZFC} \nvdash \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $, i.e., $ \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $ is not provable in $ \mathsf{ZFC} $.

Does anyone know of an authoritative reference that contains the claim that $ \neg \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $ is also not provable in $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ if $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ is consistent?

Thanks!

Comment: If ZFC is $\omega$-consistent, then $\lnot \mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{ZFC})$ is not provable. (If it were, then by $\omega$-consistency, ZFC is inconsistent – a contradiction!)

Comment: There is nothing special about ZFC in this regard. The assumptions needed will be the same as for any other theory, and the authoritative reference would just be any reference on the incompleteness theorems. If you are looking for a good book on those, I recommend the one by Peter Smith.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Hi Zhen Lin. Is there any way we can relax $ \omega $-consistency to just consistency? If not, then it seems that the second paragraph of Section 5.2 of [this Stanford Encyclopedia article](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/) is incorrect.

Comment: @CarlMummert: Hi Carl. Thanks for your comment. I agree with you — I only used $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ as an example of a theory into which $ \mathsf{PA} $ can be embedded. According to Zhen Lin’s comment, $ \omega $-consistency seems to be an assumption that one must make, but I’m wondering if consistency alone is sufficient.

Comment: My question stems from my study of the following well-known result: If $ \mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $ is consistent, then
$$
\mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \nvdash \mathsf{SM},
$$
where $ \mathsf{SM} $ is the arithmetical statement that there exists a standard model of $ \mathsf{ZFC} $. Now, compare this with the following claim: If $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ is consistent, then
$$
\mathsf{ZFC} \nvdash \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \to \mathsf{SM}.
$$

Comment: As Asaf's answer alludes, consistency alone is not enough, because ZFC + $\lnot \text{Con}(\text{ZFC})$ is consistent and proves its own inconsistency.

Comment: By the Deduction/Resolution Theorem of first-order logic, the claim is equivalent to: If $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ is consistent, then
$$
\mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \nvdash \mathsf{SM}.
$$
The result and the claim differ because the former assumes the consistency of $ \mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $ while the latter assumes the consistency of $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ alone.

Comment: @CarlMummert: Thanks! I posted right after your last comment.

Comment: One could also weaken the assumption of $\omega$-consistency to that of $\Sigma^0_1$-soundness to get the desired result.

Comment: @user52534: Hi user52534. Were you referring to the result in my post or the claim in my comments?

Comment: I was referring to the question in the post along with Zhen Lin's comment. Zhen Lin said: "If $ZFC$ is $\omega$-consistent, then $\neg$Con$(ZFC)$ is not provable (from $ZFC$)". I'm saying that we also have: "If $ZFC$ is $\Sigma^0_1$-sound, then $\neg$Con$(ZFC)$ is not provable (from $ZFC$)". The significance being that $\Sigma^0_1$-soundness is a weaker condition than $\omega$-consistency.

Comment: @user52534: Thank you, user52534. I appreciate your insight into this matter very much. I’m not sure if I can trouble you with the question that I asked Asaf in my comments below his answer. Based on your previous comment, one can prove that $ \mathsf{ZFC} \nvdash \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \to \mathsf{SM} $ if $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ is $ \Sigma^{0}_{1} $-sound, but it seems that one cannot do this by merely assuming that $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ is consistent.

Comment: Since the statement $SM$ isn't $\Sigma^0_1$, then I can see no guarantee of proving: "If $ZFC$ is $\Sigma^0_1$-sound, then $ZFC\nvdash$Con$(ZFC)\implies SM$". (Correct me if I'm wrong about the complexity of $SM$). Also, as the guys have said in the comments and answers, the statement in the Stanford article may be assuming something stronger than the consistency of $ZFC$ in its claim that Con$(ZFC)$ is independent of $ZFC$. A good example, in this FOM thread http://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2009-May/013712.html, the possibility of a consistent $ZFC$ such that $ZFC\vdash\neg$Con$(ZFC)$ is open.

Comment: @user52534: Thanks for the link! It makes a lot more sense now. The reason for my last comment goes like this (I might be making mistakes here). If $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ is $ \Sigma^{0}_{1} $-sound, then $ \mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $ is consistent because (as you’ve pointed out) $ \mathsf{ZFC} \nvdash \neg \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $. It now follows from Gödel’s Second Incompleteness Theorem (cf. my and Asaf’s comments below) that
$$
\mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \nvdash \mathsf{SM},
$$
or equivalently,
$$
\mathsf{ZFC} \nvdash \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \to \mathsf{SM}.
$$

Comment: Never mind, you are right. If $ZFC$ is $\Sigma^0_1$-sound, then $ZFC+$ Con$(ZFC)$ is consistent and so $ZFC\vdash$Con$(ZFC)\implies SM$ would lead to $ZFC$+ Con$(ZFC)$ proving it's own consistency, which is a contradiction. So yeah, we do have "If $ZFC$ is $\Sigma^0_1$-sound, then $ZFC\nvdash$Con$(ZFC)\implies SM$", just like you said.

Comment: @user52534: Yes! I’ve finally found someone who understands what I’m driving at. My question was: Can ‘$ \mathsf{ZFC} $ is $ \Sigma^{0}_{1} $-sound’ be relaxed to just ‘$ \mathsf{ZFC} $ is consistent’? Well, based on our discussions, it seems not, but Asaf believes otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

This is just not true.

Suppose that $\sf ZFC+\operatorname{Con}(ZFC)$ is just inconsistent, and the additional assumption is the one causing the inconsistency. What does that mean? It means that in every model of $\sf ZFC$ it holds that $\lnot\operatorname{Con}\sf (ZFC)$, and therefore it is provable from $\sf ZFC$ that $\lnot\operatorname{Con}\sf (ZFC)$.

Of course if you believe that inaccessible cardinals, for example, are not inconsistent with $\sf ZFC$, then you have all the reason to believe that $\sf ZFC$ does not prove that $\lnot\operatorname{Con}\sf (ZFC)$. Why? Because $\sf ZFC+\exists\kappa\text{ inaccessible}\vdash\operatorname{Con}(ZFC)$.

Comment: Hi Asaf. Thank you for your answer. Hence, if I want to prove that
$$
\mathsf{ZFC} \nvdash \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \to \mathsf{SM},
$$
then I have to assume in the first place that $ \mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $ is consistent because the consistency of $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ alone is not enough? My comments made below my post will explain to you the motivation behind my question.

Comment: No, working with $\sf ZFC$ is just fine. All you have to do is note that $\sf ZFC+SM\vdash\operatorname{Con}(ZFC+\operatorname{Con}(ZFC))$. Therefore by the second incompleteness theorem, if $\sf ZFC$ would have proved that $\sf\operatorname{Con}(ZFC)\rightarrow SM$, then $\sf ZFC+\operatorname{Con}(ZFC)$ would have proved its own consistency.

Comment: Hmm... There’s still something that I’m not getting. As you’ve said,
$$
\mathsf{ZFC} + \mathsf{SM} \vdash
\text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})),
$$
or equivalently,
$$
\mathsf{ZFC} \vdash
\mathsf{SM} \to \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})).
$$
Hence, if $ \mathsf{ZFC} \vdash \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \to \mathsf{SM} $, then
$$
\mathsf{ZFC} \vdash
\text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \to
\text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})),
$$
or equivalently,
$$
\mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \vdash
\text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})).
$$

Comment: By Gödel’s Second Incompleteness Theorem, $ \mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $ is inconsistent. This isn’t yet a contradiction as we’ve only assumed that $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ is consistent. It now follows that $ \mathsf{ZFC} \vdash \neg \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $, like in your post. Hence, how does this lead to the contradiction that we want in order to say that
$$
\mathsf{ZFC} \nvdash \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \to \mathsf{SM}
$$
without appealing to faith in the existence of inaccessible cardinals? Forgive me if I’m slow to grasp your points!

Comment: Well, it's quite obvious that $\sf ZFC+SM\vdash\operatorname{Con}(ZFC)$. If $\sf ZFC$ has *any* model then it is consistent, let alone a standard model.