# Do we know if the consistency of $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ is sufficient to prove that $ \mathsf{ZFC} \nvdash \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \to \mathsf{SM} $?

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic, incompleteness

This is basically a sequel to [this earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236980/reference-request-for-the-independence-of-textcon-mathsfzfc). There, I asked:

> If $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ is consistent, then is $ \mathsf{ZFC} \nvdash \neg \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $, i.e., $ \neg \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $ is unprovable in $ \mathsf{ZFC} $?

If $ \mathsf{I} $ denotes the sentence ⟪There exists an inaccessible cardinal⟫, then the enlightening response provided by Asaf to my question says:

> **Asaf’s response.** If
>   $$
> (\spadesuit) \quad
> \mathsf{ZFC} ~ \text{is consistent} ~ \Longrightarrow ~
> \mathsf{ZFC} + \mathsf{I} ~ \text{is consistent},
> $$
>   then $ \mathsf{ZFC} \nvdash \neg \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $ when $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ is consistent.

As is well-known, $ (\spadesuit) $ is an open question in set theory.

The motivation behind my question is the following theorem:

> **Theorem.** If $ \mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $ is consistent, then $ \mathsf{ZFC} \nvdash \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \to \mathsf{SM} $, where $ \mathsf{SM} $ is the statement in the language of set theory saying that there exists a standard model of $ \mathsf{ZFC} $.

For the sake of convenience, let me provide a proof.

*Proof*

Suppose that $ \mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $ is consistent. As the sentence $ \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $ is absolute, we have
$$
\mathsf{ZFC} \vdash
\mathsf{SM} \to \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})).
$$
Assume for the sake of contradiction that $ \mathsf{ZFC} \vdash \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \to \mathsf{SM} $. Then *modus ponens* yields
$$
\mathsf{ZFC} \vdash
\text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \to \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})).
$$
By the Resolution Theorem of first-order logic, we obtain
$$
\mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \vdash
\text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})),
$$
which contradicts Gödel’s Second Incompleteness Theorem as $ \mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $ was assumed to be a consistent theory. $ \quad \blacksquare $

My question is:

> **Question.** **Do we know** if we can relax ‘$ \mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $ is consistent’ to simply ‘$ \mathsf{ZFC} $ is consistent’ in order for the theorem to hold still?

If the consistency of $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ implies the consistency of $ \mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $, then we are done by the theorem above. This is the reason for my earlier post. If $ \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $ is independent of $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ when $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ is consistent, then $ \mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $ is consistent when $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ is consistent and the theorem follows.

Also in my earlier post, Zhen Lin mentioned that if $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ is $ \omega $-consistent, then $ \neg \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $ is not provable in $ \mathsf{ZFC} $. user52534 also suggested that if $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ is $ \Sigma^{0}_{1} $-sound, then we get the same thing. Hence, we can replace ‘$ \mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $ is consistent’ by ‘$ \mathsf{ZFC} $ is $ \omega $-consistent’ or even better, ‘$ \mathsf{ZFC} $ is $ \Sigma^{0}_{1} $-sound’.

I would therefore appreciate an answer to my question in one of the following three forms:

- ‘Yes’ with a careful proof sketch (for a beginner like myself) or a reference.
- ‘No’ with a careful proof sketch or a reference.
- ‘This is an open problem’ with a reference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me first clarify the issue with an inaccessible, since it seems to me that my words were somewhat misunderstood.

1. I only mentioned inaccessible cardinals, since it is a plausible axiom, and if you believe it to be consistent, then of course there will be a (standard) model of $\sf ZFC$. And in that case we cannot prove $\sf\lnot\operatorname{Con}(ZFC)$.

   What I didn't say is that "If the consistency of $\sf ZFC$ implies the consistency of $\sf ZFC+I$ then ..." because we can easily show that this cannot be the case, unless $\sf ZFC$ was inconsistent to begin with.
2. It is not an open question whether or not inaccessible cardinals are consistent. We know that this statement cannot be proved. Whether or not inaccessible cardinals are *inconsistent* is an open question, but I don't think any set theorist today believes that.

The point is that in some mathematical universes, $\sf ZFC$ is consistent, but $\sf ZFC+\operatorname{Con}(ZFC)$ is not consistent. In those universes, $\sf ZFC$ *proves* its own inconsistency, which sounds weird, and indeed those universes will necessarily disagree with the meta-theory about the integers, so as far as models of set theory go, they will be non-standard models.

But in such mathematical universe, $\sf ZFC\vdash\lnot\operatorname{Con}(ZFC)$. And therefore, for *any* statement $\varphi$, $\sf ZFC\vdash\operatorname{Con}(ZFC)\rightarrow\varphi$. Simply because a false premise implies everything.

Finally, we can relax the assumption on $\sf\operatorname{Con}(ZFC)$ and essentially require that $\sf\operatorname{Con}(ZFC)$ is not refutable. This follows from both $\omega$-consistency and $\Sigma^0_1$-soundness.

Comment: Thank you, Asaf! This is much clearer for me now. I had my own doubts when I wrote $ (\spadesuit) $ down. When $ (\spadesuit) $ is formalized within $ \mathsf{ZFC} $, it cannot be proven if $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ is consistent. It was meant to be a sentence in the meta-theory, and it definitely cannot be proven if we assume that the external $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ on which the meta-theory is based is consistent. In order to discuss the consistency of the external $ \mathsf{ZFC} $, we need a meta-meta-theory.

Comment: I was thinking that if we stay within the meta-theory, then although we know in our guts that $ (\spadesuit) $ cannot be proven, strictly speaking, we have to pass over it in silence, like how Wittgenstein would put it.

Comment: Also, if you could, would you provide me with a reference to these strange mathematical universes in which $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ actually proves $ \neg \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $? Thanks!

Comment: One thing to note is that in the meta-theory we assume $\sf\operatorname{Con}(ZFC)$, otherwise the entire thing is moot. And the proofs that various things like inaccessible cardinals imply the consistency of $\sf ZFC$ can be done in very weak meta-theories. So the choice of meta-theory is moot here. As for your second question, take a model of $\sf ZFC$ in which there are no models for $\sf ZFC+\operatorname{Con}(ZFC)$, and internally to that model (i.e. the model is now the meta-theory) it will be true that $\sf ZFC$ is consistent, but proves its own inconsistency.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I've always understood the metatheory in set theory as implicitly finitist, in the sense that the goal is to establish (p.r.) algorithms that convert proofs, such as you hand me a proof of $\text{ZFC} + \mathfrak{c} = \aleph_7 \vdash \varphi$ for some arithmetical $\varphi$ and I find some algorithm that provably turns it into a proof of $\text{ZFC} \vdash \varphi$. I also never thought of the metatheory to have an associated model. (cont.)

Comment: When you say that _"those universes will necessarily disagree with the meta-theory about the integers"_ do you mean that the models of ZFC constructed in those universes will have natural numbers that are not isomorphic to the natural numbers of whatever model we associate with the metatheory? But this is then a sort of meta-meta theorem, or just an informal observation, if you will. Right? Because the meta-theory doesn't know about the model we informally associate with it (like how most mathematicians think of the cumulative hierarchy when doing work in ZFC).

Comment: I'm just trying to get a grasp of what is formal and what is informal talk, and where such talk is happening.

Comment: @Jori: No, that's not the case. We know how to recursively transform our proofs from a set theoretic meta-theory to a finitistic meta-theory. This is one of the main reason why canonical inner models, and explicit constructions of a generic extension (using parameters) are so important. And so we can assume that the meta-theory of ZFC is in fact... ZFC.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh, okay. I don't know about that, it's not in the Kunen book I'm sure. I suppose I'll get across it when I go further into set theory. Can you clarify if I understood correctly (more or less) the meaning of _"those universes will necessarily disagree with the meta-theory about the integers"_? Specifically what you mean with a model of a metatheory.

Comment: @Jori: If $V$ is our whole universe of sets, and $M$ is a set model of ZFC, if $M$ agrees with $V$ on $\omega$, i.e. it is an $\omega$-model, then it agrees with $V$ on what is ZFC and what are the inference rules of FOL and what are the statements that ZFC proves and disproves. In particular, since in $V$ we have that ZFC is consistent, this is ultimately an arithmetic statement, and so it is true in $M$ as well. It follows that if $V$ thinks that ZFC is consistent, but $M$ disagrees, then $V$ and $M$ disagree on $\omega$. [...]

Comment: [...] The thing is that "*normally*" we are not in a situation where ZFC is consistent but "ZFC+Con(ZFC)" is not. Rather we have that ZFC is not only consistent, every recursive iteration of the consistency predicate is also consistent. For example, if we have an $\omega$-model. So it turns out that $V$ itself is actually a non-standard model from *our* even-more-meta point of view. But in any case, the important thing to distinguish is that between $V$ and $M$ the two disagree on the natural numbers.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah, so what you say is that if we informally think about $V$ as the "true" universe described by our metatheory, which we assume here is $\text{ZFC}, \text{Con}(\text{ZFC}), \text{ZFC} \vdash \neg\text{Con}(\text{ZFC})$, we must contend that the models of (ZFC-) set theory (the subject matter of set theory) we study in this universe disagree with $V$ (the metatheory) about what the natural numbers are. This is because if $N$ was an $\omega$-model then $N \models \neg\text{Con}(\text{ZFC})$ implies $\neg\text{Con}(\text{ZFC})$ in $V$, while also $\text{Con}(\text{ZFC})$ there.

Comment: @Jori: Exactly. And in fact, we can see they $V$ disagrees with us, if we work in a strong enough meta theory, for the same reason.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What do you mean? We took $V$ as the metatheory, right? Or do you mean in the scenario of an _even_ more meta perspective where we look at different possible metatheories, while having in our mind a "true" metatheory, for example one with an inaccessible cardinal, which would imply that the metatheory associated to $V$ (now just a model) implies it has non-standard numbers (for the very same reason as I just stated)?

Comment: Still, as far as I understand it, it could be that ZFC really is consistent while proving that it is internally inconsistent, in the proof theoretic sense. I'm not sure what that would say about ZFC, if someone came up with a completely formal proof in ZFC of $\neg\text{Con}(\text{ZFC})$. Would we discard ZFC or discard that $\text{Con}(\text{ZFC})$ says what we think it says?

Comment: @Jori: In V's meta universe, we have a model (namely V) of ZFC + Con(ZFC), but no model of ZFC + Con(ZFC + Con(ZFC)). Turtles all the way down, baby!

Answer (score 2):

To summarize, and to answer the question, it seems that we have an unknown problem.

The reason being: the OP has established "If $ZFC\nvdash$ $\neg$Con$(ZFC)$, then $ZFC\nvdash$ Con$(ZFC)$ $\implies  SM$." in the statement of his question. Also, Asaf has established (the almost trivial) "If $ZFC\vdash$ $\neg$Con$(ZFC)$, then $ZFC\vdash$ Con$(ZFC)$ $\implies  SM$."

Putting these two together, we have established "$ZFC\vdash$ $\neg$Con$(ZFC)$ if and only if $ZFC\vdash$ Con$(ZFC)$ $\implies  SM$.

(*) So since it is not known whether $ZFC\vdash$ $\neg$Con$(ZFC)$ or not (even under the extra assumption that $ZFC$ is consistent), then it follows from the above paragraph that is not know whether $ZFC\vdash$ Con$(ZFC)$ $\implies  SM$ or not (even under the extra assumption that $ZFC$ is consistent).

Regarding (*): It is a big assumption for me to say that something is not known, so the best I can do is to direct you to the discussion about the arithmetic soundness of $ZFC$ over at FOM, where the posters dabble in the possibility of a consistent $ZFC$ such that $ZFC\vdash$ $\neg$Con$(ZFC)$.

Comment: This is not much of an open problem, just provably unprovable. Not to mention that in the case that $\sf ZFC\vdash\lnot\operatorname{Con}(ZFC)$, the model and the meta-theory disagree on the integers, which gives a good philosophical justification, in my opinion, why this is not really the case.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I take it you don't believe in a consistent but arithmetically unsound $ZFC$.

Comment: I don't believe in anything. I just find the idea of using an unsound foundational theory a bit... strange.

Comment: Thanks, Sam. You’ve put it very nicely. I prefer saying “It’s an open problem” or “I don’t know” to contending with phrases like ‘provably unprovable’.

Comment: @Berrick: But that's not true. An open problem is a problem whose solution is not known. We *know* the solution. The solution is that it depends on the meta-theory (i.e. is $\sf ZFC$ arithmetically sound?), is the Riemann Hypothesis true is an open problem. Is $\sf CH$ true is not.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What do you mean exactly when you say "The solution is that it depends on the meta-theory"? I'm asking because any meta-theory strong enough to prove the claim "$\mathsf{ZFC}\nvdash\neg\mathsf{RH}$" will itself be strong enough to actually establish $\mathsf{RH}$. So in this situation, the solution to $\mathsf{RH}$ will (as you put it) "depend on the meta-theory".

Comment: @user52534: You're being too literal. Replace $\sf RH$ by any generic question whose answer we don't know. For sake of specificity, "Is the axiom of choice equivalent to the partition principle in $\sf ZF$" coming off the top of my head.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Asaf, are you trying to say that because our problem has now been bumped up to the **meta-level** to read ‘Is the consistency of $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ equivalent to the consistency of $ \mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $?’, by Gödel’s Second Incompleteness Theorem, formulated in the meta-meta-theory and applied to the meta-theory (assuming it is consistent), the answer must be ‘no’?

Comment: @Berrick: I am saying that an open problem is a problem whose answer we don't know. We know the answer here, the answer is "Not enough data to say yes or no". And as Godel showed, that is a valid mathematical answer to a question. Let me ask this, in the theory of fields, is $\exists x(x\cdot x=1+1)$ an "open problem"? Namely is the problem "Does $\sqrt2$ exists?" open when considering the language of rings and theory of fields?